# Shift Cipher without knowing the key in c

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, switch-statement

I am writing a program to solve a random code.(the code will not have capital letters,any form of signs like full stop) The code is using shift cipher without knowing the key,it can also encrypt code but i will work on that one later.For now i am trying to output all 25 result first.

However if i enter things like "back to back",it will output a question mark at the end.

Here's my code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char code[400];
  char after[400];  // variable initialization
  int i, x, choice, z, temp, y;
  printf("                     Welcome\n");
  printf("Enter your code here:\n");
  scanf("%[^'\n']s", code);
  printf("Press 1 to Decrypt\nPress 2 to encrypt\nPress 3 to Exit\n");
  scanf("%d", &choice);

  // case 1 is decryption
  switch (choice) {
    case 1:
      for (x = 1; x <= 25; x++) {
        for (i = 0; (i <= 400 && code[i] != 0); i++)  // for loop
        {
          if (code[i] == 32) {  // 32 means space in ascii code
            after[i] = 32;
            continue;  // if there is a space it will continue
          }
          if (code[i] + x > 122) {  // 122 is z in ascii code
            after[i] = code[i] + x;  // if it is higher than 'z'
            after[i] = (after[i] - 122) + 96;  // it start counting form 'a'
            continue;
          } else {
            after[i] = code[i] + x;
            // if nothing is wrong,it starting adding the key
          }
        }
        printf("After decrypting:%s\n", after);
        printf("%s\n", code);
      }
      break;

    // case 2 is ecnrypt so its not important
    case 2:
      x = 5;
      for (i = 0; (i <= 400 && code[i] != 0); i++)  // for loop
      {
        if (code[i] == ' ') {
          continue;
        }
        if (code[i] + x > 122) {
          code[i] = code[i] + x;
          code[i] = (code[i] - 122) + 96;
          continue;
        } else {
          code[i] = code[i] + x;
        }
      }
      printf("After decrypting:%s", code);
      break;

    // not important as well
    case 3:
      printf("GOODBYE");
      break;

    // not important as well
    default:
      printf("Errors");
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve a shift cipher all you need is a dictionary and the first ten words or so of your ciphertext. Try all possibilities and test each “decoded” plaintext word against your dictionary. Choose the cipher with the highest match rate.

Comment: This does not appear to answer their question: "However if i enter things like "back to back",it will output a question mark at the end."

Comment: Is it possible to find the code with the highest frequency of ‘e’ since it’s the most popular letter in English? I think it’s hard to copy the whole dictionary and match with the code. Thanks for ur suggestions :D

Comment: @SirJamesLongbottom You would need a relatively long cipher text for that to reliably work. Consider your example of "back to back", which has no e's.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that all the code have around 400 words, back to back is just a test case to try :(

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to null terminate `after`.

Perhaps you should do:

```
    for (i = 0; (i <= 400 && code[i] != 0); i++) {
      if (code[i] == 32) {
        after[i] = ...
      } else if (code[i] + x > 122) {
        after[i] = ...
      } else {
        after[i] = ...
      }
    }
    after[i] = '\0'; // <-- This line is missing.
    printf("After decrypting:%s\n", after);
    printf("%s\n", code);
```